# External users cannot see info in metadata field

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

I just created a document library and invited a guest user with edit-access. Created a customized meta-data field and added some terms in the termset. Then added three files and attached the terms to them.

The owner & other internal users can view the terms that has been set on the items in the library. But guest users cannot. I have reproduced the same issue in three different tenants today. Also tried to give the guestuser full control of the site, but this issue still remains.

Have tried both the local termstore and the global one. Same issue.

Can anyone else reproduce this strange behavior and what could possibly be wrong?

Library view from the organizational user:
[image]

Library view from the guest user:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is happening on multiple tenants and I've seen this on other forums. I have notified Microsoft of this issue. I would recommend submitting a support ticket to Microsoft.

In the mean-time, I believe you can manually add the users read permissions back to the taxonomy hidden list, to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding the external user to the **Taxonomy Hidden List** permission list via `http://<siteurl>/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList`

The hidden list should have *Anonymous Users* assigned with “**View Items**” permission by default.

[image]

Since there is no “Anonymous Users” or “Everyone” (*NT Authority\Authenticated* or *NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON*) permission to assign in SharePoint Online, you can manually assign View Only / Read permission to the external user.

Or simply remove the unique permission of this list will do as well (not recommended though).

Answer (score 0):

This was, as you are saying, a temporary issue at Microsoft.
It's working now without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

The Managed Metadata Keywords Filtering feature does not work for users who have Read Only permissions and requires users to have at least Contribute permissions. I manage multiple standards libraries for a major electric utility and this has been a problem for us. Adding users to the Taxonomy Hidden List doesn't fix the problem.